# Equating powers in a series expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

> If the $(r+1)^{th}$ term contains the same power of $a$ and $b$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{\sqrt b}}+\sqrt{\frac {b}{\sqrt[3]{a}}}\bigg)^{21}$$
>   find the value of $r$

I simply applied binomial and expanded for the general term and then equated the power of $a$ and $b$ and got $r=12$

My friend got $r=9$

I want to know which answer is correct.

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying to replicate your calculations, you're probably using version of the binomial theorem that count the terms from the opposite end. You can state the theorem either as
$$ (p+q)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} p^r q^{n-r} $$
or as
$$ (p+q)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} p^{n-r} q^r $$
which both give the same terms, just with a different numbering.

Note in particular that $9+12=21$, so you can both be right, if you're counting from different ends of the expansion!

Answer (score 2):

On simplifying the following expression: $$\bigg(\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{\sqrt b}}+\sqrt{\frac {b}{\sqrt[3]{a}}}\bigg)^{21}$$
We get the expression:
$$\frac{1}{(ab)^\frac72}\bigg(a^\frac12+b^\frac23\bigg)^{21}$$

So the (r$+1$)th term of the expansion is $$\binom{n}{r}a^{\frac{21-r-7}{2}}b^{\frac{4r-21}{6}}$$

Hence, the answer will come as:
$$\frac{21-r-7}{2}=\frac{4r-21}{6}$$
$$\Rightarrow 42-3r=4r-21$$
$$\Rightarrow \boxed{\color{red}{r=9}}$$

The required answer is $9$.

Comment: couldn't it be 12 as 12+9=21?

Comment: The first step here looks somewhat obscure. Why not simplify to $$ (a^{1/3}b^{-1/6}+a^{-1/6}b^{1/2})^{21}$$ and then solve $$ \frac13r - \frac16(21-r) = -\frac16 r + \frac12(21-r) $$

Comment: @AtulMishra Well, in a problem, where the binomial expression is rigorously given, it is expected that you consider the first term as the 'a' term and the second one 'b'. So if you consider the expansion in this order, your answer should be 9. I saw Henning's answer, but I dont think that you are allowed to reverse the expression and work. It may seem trivial that you cannot reverse the expression but if one is allowed to do so, then the ordering of the terms will become ambiguous and there will be no unique answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I am just arguing for the same, It will give r=12

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: There's no "reversing" going on -- there's just two ways to state the binomial theorem _which are exactly equally good_. It's not as if one of them is "the right way" and the other is "reversed".

Comment: @AtulMishra I said that! It sounds trivial. Surely addition is commutative. But then as I said, how do you explain the ordering? READ my first comment in total.

Comment: I agree with you that to define the order , one rule must be followed, but there could be possibility of two answers....

Comment: @HenningMakholm I said it ... pls read my first comment. Addition is commutative .. sure.  But if the first term according to me is the last term according to you, then there is no uniqueness in the ordering and the answer. Thats what I want to say. Nothing did I say about right or wrong ... pls note that.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: Everything you say implies that you think that one of the orders is "reversed" and one is not. That is simply not true! They are _both_ valid explansions of the binomial, and neither order is more "reversed" than the other one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm In the truest sense, yes both are equally reversed. And there is no unique answer. But say its an assignment or a homework... which answer must one go for? And if one goes for both... the "reverse" logic has to be given. AGAIN, both answers are valid but from different points of view. THERE IS NO UNIQUENESS in that case.